# Charge 2 18650s with eBay charger + pcb

Tags: voltage, batteries, pcb, charger, lipo

I'm currently building my own Bluetooth Box and need a portable power supply.
For that I use two 18650s LiPos and a PCB Protection board.
PCB Protection board:
https://rover.ebay.com/rover/0/0/0?mpre=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.ebay.de%2Fulk%2Fitm%2F253581817900
For charging I will need an extra charging board. 
I found this on eBay:
https://rover.ebay.com/rover/0/0/0?mpre=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.ebay.de%2Fulk%2Fitm%2F112195812078
Will my two Lipos charge when I connect the outputs of this board to the p+ and p- pins of the PCB or am I missing a component? 
The output voltage of the batteries is stepped down to 6.5 V. Can I use the bt Box while charging?

[image: Circuit]

Comment: Please provide a block diagram or use the schematic tool to document your setup

Comment: Added my circuit